# converting string into json array with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert string into json array and the iterate over it.

```
            String name = "lokesh";
            String response = "[{"name":"lokesh"}, {"name":"cherukuri"}]";

            JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(response, JsonArray.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
                if (jsonObject.get("name").toString().equals(name)) {
                    System.out.println("equal");
                }
            }
```

Problem: The If condition inside loop is not true because of quotes. because this line

```
   System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name")); // printed "lokesh"

    and System.out.println(name); //printed lokesh
```

Am i using GSON in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the "name" attribute, you need to:

```
jsonObject.getString("name")
```

So, your code should be:

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name"));
if (jsonObject.getString("name").equals(name)) {
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because jsonObject.get("name") return a *JsonElement* object.
If you're sure it's an string, you can get the content by

```
jsonObject.get("name").getAsString()
```